# Server Error in '/asp.netwebadminfiles' Application - VS 2013

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, asp.net-membership, configuration-files, iis-express

I'm working with ASP.Net web application and i want to create a membership user so i have to access the Web Configuration Tool for ASP.NET . i have run  IISExpress commands in Prompt and it's works fine but whenever i run the `http://localhost:5376/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual%20Studio%202013\Projects\MyWebsite&applicationUrl=/` in the browser i got this error !

the error message :

> Server Error in '/asp.netwebadminfiles' Application.
>
> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
> required to service this request. Please review the following specific
> error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0122: 'System.Configuration.StringUtil' is
> inaccessible due to its protection level
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 987:
>
> Line 988:             // Put together some unique app id
>
> Line 989:             string appId =StringUtil.GetNonRandomizedHashCode(String.Concat(appPath,appPhysPath)).ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
>
> Line 990:
>
> Line 991:
>
> Source File:
> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\App_Code\WebAdminPage.cs
> Line: 989

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32116493/cs0122-system-configuration-stringutil-is-inaccessible-due-to-its-protection.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx) way down in the comment from Mr_Coinche.

> For those who are encountering the "CS0122:
>   'System.Configuration.StringUtil' is inaccessible due to its
>   protection level" issue. It's the fault of .net 4.6.
>
> So you can uninstall this framework (if you are on windows 8), for
>   those who are using windows 10, it's seems difficult or impossible to
>   uninstall .net 4.6 because it's install with windows 10.
>
> So there is an alternative, you can modify the
>
> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\App_Code\WebAdminPage.cs
>   file code or
>
> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\App_Code\WebAdminPage.cs
>   , (depending which you are trying to install)
>
> Replace the line

```
string appId = StringUtil.GetNonRandomizedHashCode(String.Concat(appPath, appPhysPath)).ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> with these lines:

```
Assembly sysConfig = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Configuration.dll");
Type sysConfigType = sysConfig.GetType("System.Configuration.StringUtil");
string appId = ((int)sysConfigType.GetMethod("GetNonRandomizedHashCode")
  .Invoke(null, new object[] { String.Concat(appPath, appPhysPath), true }))
  .ToString("x", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In addition, make sure you run Notepad (or whatever code editor you choose) As Administrator, otherwise you won't have permissions to save the file once you've made the change.  I made the change to both files - it's just a different way of calling the same method, but in a way that is consistent with its new protection level in .NET 4.6