# How to reach asp configuration tools in visual studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I worked with this top solution provided on the stack over flow till now 
[Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541680/visual-studio-2013-and-asp-net-web-configuration-tool). I used it perfectly but now i have  stuck in another problem having an internal error like "CS0122: 'System.Configuration.StringUtil' is inaccessible due to its protection level"
Any help please....

Comment: Rather than continuing to use an old unsupported tool that you have to hack to work, why not write your own interface? Or use [a replacement tool](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ThinktectureIdentityManagerAsAReplacementForTheASPNETWebSiteAdministrationTool.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can comment out the code that tries to call StringUtil.  See this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32488883/3854195

Comment: yeahhh ... finally solved it!!!!! thank you :) .. why don't they fix it by theirselvers :/

Comment: @AwaisAhmad Because they don't support the tool any longer.